# buildDependencies targets folder instead of file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

For caching (`type: 'filesystem'`), when i use

```
buildDependencies: {
  config: [__filename],
}
```

and rebuild after a minimal change, I get cache to be used:

```
[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache container: 75.650361 ms
[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] check build dependencies: 38.511852 ms
[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache content metadata: 7.851668 ms
```

However, if i simply add one more file to `buildDependencies`, e.g. like this (same, if i use a new property):

```
buildDependencies: {
  config: [__filename, path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json')],
}
```

I suddenly get a cache invalidation (although `tsconfig.json` didn't change, neither did `webpack.config.js`, i obviously rebuilt in between):

```
[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache container: 79.482314 ms
[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] C:\some\nice\folder invalidated because hashes differ (somehash != someotherhash)
[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restored pack from C:\some\nice\folder\cachefolder\cachename.pack, but build dependencies have changed.
[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] check build dependencies: 593.564325 ms
```

Note that it mentions that a path ending with a folder (the project folder) invalidated, although i supposedly specified a file as dependency. The resulting build time is around twice as long.

What am i doing wrong here? Why does webpack invalidate the cache here, although none of the dependencies changed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Webpack did so far not support non-code files in `buildDependencies`, and `ts-loader` seems to not have properly declared `tsconfig.json` as a dependency (over a loader's channel), making this necessary in the first place. A fallback then used the entire folder.

Luckily, both of these should be fixed in coming versions: webpack will allow `.json` files in `buildDependencies` (if i am not mistaken in `v5.14.0`, which is already available just now), and `ts-loader` will hopefully tell webpack about `tsconfig.json` (in some future version), so it would work even without setting the dependency manually. Some related logs and errors will also change, to be more informative.